# PHP Validate DateTime using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

How to validate the below date format using reg-ex.

```
Fri, Apr 11, 2014 01:09 AM
```

Comment: Why specifically a regex? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: So you have a problem and you decide to use a regex to solve it. And now you have two problems.

Comment: @Jon : Actually i am validating the Received Email Date time in Behat automation.So i preferred regex.

Comment: @Oasis: That does not answer either of my questions. Probably tells nothing to most other people who read it as well.

Comment: @Jon: I have answered your first question. I have a date time value in  the UI.I just want to validate the UI date time value is in specific format using Automation testing.I tried some regex expressions.But nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to solve the problem using a regex, you should use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/datetime). It will be able to parse your input, like so:

```
$date = new DateTime('Fri, Apr 11, 2014 01:09 AM');
```

You could also create a DateTime from a given format

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, M j, Y h:i A', 'Fri, Apr 11, 2014 01:09 AM');
```

Comment: However, it will also happily accept many other input formats.

Comment: You could also use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and specify the format you want.

Comment: That would make for a much better answer.

Comment: I've added it with a working example.